# Open keyboard on button click in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How can I open Keyboard on Button click in Jetpack Compose? I have a button and I want the keyboard to open when I click this button. How can I do this? This is my screen and the keyboard does not open when I click:

```
@ExperimentalComposeUiApi
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    viewModel: MainScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    val number = viewModel.score.value
    val kc = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)) {
            ScoreBoard(number)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))
            Button(onClick = { viewModel.increaseScore(1) }) { Text(text = "Increase Number") }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))
            Button(onClick = {
                kc?.show()
                viewModel.startGame()
            }) { Text(text = "Start the game") }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current` to get the software keyboard controller inside a composable.

Then you can use its `show()` and `hide()` functions.

Keep in mind that the soft keyboard can usually only be opened if an input (or something that accepts input) has focus.

Since this is an experimental Compose API, you will have to annotate the parent function with `@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)` (or `@ExperimentalComposeUiApi`)

```
//@ExperimentalComposeUiApi
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun OpenKeyboardExample() {
    val kc = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    Button(
        onClick = { kc?.show() }
    ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you get warnings related to opt-in you can add the compiler argument to your `app.gradle`

```
android {
    ...
    kotlinOptions {     
        freeCompilerArgs += "-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"
    }
}
```

From `LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current` docs:

> Return a SoftwareKeyboardController that can control the current software keyboard.
> If it is not provided, the default implementation will delegate to LocalTextInputService.
> Returns null if the software keyboard cannot be controlled.

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/LocalSoftwareKeyboardController

Comment: I edited my question with adding my code, can you look at it?

Comment: @HasanCihadAltay That is okay as far as the call goes, but like I mentioned in my answer the keyboard cant just show up anytime you want, there has to be focus on "something that accepts input".